# How to trigger re-render with useEffect() in React after POST request to add data to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Apologies if this is already been asked, but cannot find an answer to my problem.
I got Firebase as a backend, it fetches the data already stored in the database, but when I add new data via POST request the fetching function in useEffect does not re-render the component.

This is my code

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

import Job from "./Job";
import classes from "./JobsList.module.css";

const URL =
  "[PLACEHOLDER]";

const JobsList = () => {
  const [jobsData, setJobsData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchJobsHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Could not fetch data");
      }

      const data = await response.json();

      const jobs = [];

      for (const key in data) {
        jobs.push({
          id: key,
          company: data[key].company,
          role: data[key].role,
          techStack: data[key].techStack,
          location: data[key].location,
          appliedDate: data[key].appliedDate,
        });
      }

      setJobsData(jobs);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchJobsHandler();
  }, [fetchJobsHandler]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading... Please wait</p>;
  }

  if (!jobsData) {
    return <p>Add a job application</p>;
  }

  return (
    <ul className={classes["jobs-list"]}>
      {jobsData.map((job) => (
        <Job
          key={job.id}
          company={job.company}
          role={job.role}
          techStack={job.techStack}
          location={job.location}
          appliedDate={job.appliedDate}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default JobsList;
```

Any help will be very much appreciated it

Comment: Are you sure `setJobsData` was called in `fetchJobsHandler`?

Comment: Hi, yes I called it passing it the new jobs array, or have I missed something? Thanks